# Notepad++ replace with spaces

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using a regex in Notepad++ I am trying to replace 53 characters on a line with spaces:

```
Find: (^RS.{192})(.{53})(.{265})
Replace: \1(\x20){53}\3
```

It's replacing group `\2` with `" {53}"` but what I want is 53 spaces.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacement terms are not regex expressions, except they may use back references.

Just code 53 literal spaces:

```
Replace: \1                                                     \3
```

A bit tedious, but it works.

Comment: This is what I went with. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

space is `\s`

which means you need to use `\s{53}`

Comment: Not in the replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is ALLWAYS RS and 192 characters before and 265 after

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^RS.{192}|\G)\K.(?=.{265,}$)`
- Replace with:   # a space
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # start non capture group
    ^           # beginning of line
    RS          # literally RS
    .{192}      # 192 any character
  |             # R
    \G          # restart from last match position
)               # end group
\K              # forget all we've seen until this position
.               # 1 any character
(?=             # positive lookahead, zero-length assertion to make sure we have after:
    .{265,}     # at least 256 any characters
    $           # end of line
)               # en lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
%           # the character to insert
```

**Given shorter line to illusrate:**

```
RSabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

**Result for given example:**

```
RSabcdefghij      qrstuvwxyz
```

**Screen shot:**

[image]